# If $a_i >0$ ($i=1, 2, \cdots , n$), then prove this inequality

Tags: inequality

If $a_i >0$ ($i=1, 2, \cdots , n$), then $$\left (\frac{a_1}{a_2} \right )^k + \left (\frac{a_2}{a_3} \right )^k + \cdots + \left (\frac{a_n}{a_1} \right )^k \geq \frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\cdots + \frac{a_n}{a_1}$$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Here i tried to reduce the powers with weighted AM-GM but could not do it much

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. Just in case that you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Thanks...Its true i am unaware of many of the things in this website

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_j = a_j/a_{j+1}$ (with $a_{n+1} = a_1$) and let $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ be a non-increasing rearrangement of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Using [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) and the AM-GM inequality we can prove the inequality for all *real numbers* $k > 1$:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^k \ge \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^{k-1} \right)\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \right)
\ge \sqrt[n]{y_1^{k-1} \cdots y_n^{k-1}} \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \right)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n y_j 
$$
and therefore
$$
 \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}}\right)^k \ge  \sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}} \, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $b_j = \frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}}$. Apply AM-GM inequality : 
For each index $i$ from $1$ to $n$:
$b_i^k + 1+1+...+1 \ge kb_i$ ( $k-1$ such $1$ ).
Add them up . And rearrange to show again by AM-GM inequality : $b_1+ b_2+...+b_n \ge n$ which is clear since $b_1\cdot b_2\cdots b_n = 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $b_i^k + 1+\ldots+1 \ge kb_i$?

Comment: Yes, I thought $b_i$ but when I typed its $a_i$. Thanks for pointing out Martin.

Comment: Nice solution! ${}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}}=x_i$, we have that $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}=1$. The function $f(x)=x^k$ is convex, so by Jensen we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^k &\geq  n\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}\right)^k \\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \right)\cdot \left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}\right)^{k-1} \\
&\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i
\end{align*}where the last inequality follows from AM-GM.

But i want to use at max AM-GM inequality. Is there any other way